# Compare Dates in Array of MongoDB Object with different formats

Tags: javascript, arrays, datepicker, momentjs

I am using a datepicker in my frontend which sends a date using an AJAX Request. 
Now this date is in the format - 'YYYY-MM-DD'. I have an array of dates which I have to compare this date with and pick out which are equal. This array is from a Mongo DB collection where I have TimeZone included in the field as well, for example - "2020-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"

**My Slot Json Object**

```
{
  date: [
    2020-06-03T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-06-05T00:00:00.000Z,
    2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```

I have to loop over each date in the date array and compare it with the date I get from frontend.

Let's say user input date is

```
let userInput = '2020-06-03';
```

And now I have to compare it with the date array
How do I ensure that the following comparision leads me to get a true value for

```
'2020-06-03' and '2020-06-03T00:00:00.000Z'
```

I am looking at a solution which is appropriate when looping over all these array elements.

Answer (score 0):

assuming, that your date array always is at 00:00:00 o'clock, i'd suggest something like this:

```js
const dates = [
  '2020-06-03T00:00:00.000Z',
  '2020-06-05T00:00:00.000Z',
  '2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z'
];

let userInput = '2020-06-03';

function findDates(date) {
  const searchDate = Date.parse(date);
  const foundDates = [];

  dates.forEach(date => {
    const tempDate = Date.parse(date);

    if (tempDate === searchDate) {
      foundDates.push(date);
    }
  });

  return foundDates;
}

console.log(findDates(userInput));
```

if there's more to consider, please say so

Answer (score 0):

Have the format of date strings(input) and the array of dates be properly specified for parsing. Then you could straight away use the `isSame()` to check if the dates are equal

```js
let input = "2020-06-03";
let arr = [
  "2020-06-03T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-06-05T00:00:00.000Z",
  "2020-06-07T00:00:00.000Z"
];
let result = arr.map(item =>
  moment(item, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss zz").isSame(input, "YYYY-MM-DD")
);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```